# My code is not showing an output when I am trying to find the largest number among three numbers in C++

Tags: c++

This Is My Code
I Am A Beginner
Whenever I run my code it takes the input for the three numbers but sometimes mostly when the given numbers are small is doesn't give back an output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int num1, num2, num3;
   cout << "Enter First Number" << endl;
   cin >> num1;
   cout << "Enter Second Number" << endl;
   cin >> num2;
   cout << "Enter Third Number" << endl;
   cin >> num3;
   if (num1 > num2)
   {
      if (num1 > num3)
      {
         cout << "First Number Is The Largest";
      }
   }
   else if (num2 > num1)
   {
      if (num2 > num3)
      {
         cout << "Second Number Is The Largest";
      }
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Third Number Is The Largest";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if `num1 > num2` is true, but `num1 > num3` is false?

Comment: @Rudraksha Paul What are you going to output if the user will enter three equal numbers?

Comment: Have a look at the standard [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) algorithm for this, eg: `#include <algorithm> int nums[3]; cin >> nums[0]; cin >> nums[1]; cin >> nums[2]; cout << *std::max_element(nums, nums+3) << " Is The Largest";` Or, the [`std::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) algorithm, eg: `#include <algorithm> int num1, num2, num3; cin >> num1; cin >> num2; cin >> num3; cout << std::max({num1, num2, num3}) << " Is The Largest";`

Comment: I wouldn't even bother with an array for this input size. I'd just check each new input against the max. You just need two variables. I suppose it depends on if you actually have to say first, second, or third.

Answer (score 1):

My thought is you're trying to get more complicated then necessary:

```
   if (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3)
   {    
      cout << "First Number Is The Largest";
   }
   else if (num2 >= num1 && num2 >= num3)
   {
      cout << "Second Number Is The Largest";
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Third Number Is The Largest";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are not testing equal numbers, e.g: `num1 >= num2`. Also:

```
 if (num1 > num2)
   {
      if (num1 > num3)
      {
         cout << "First Number Is The Largest";
      }
   }
```

You check if `num1 > num2`, but if `num3 == num 1` or `num 3 > num1` it will not appear a message. Try to put a message in the first `if` to show if it doesn't enter in second `if`, and then you can edit all the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a requirement that you say "First", "Second", or "Third", but if it's not, your code can be simplified down to something like this (this assumes you haven't learned about loops yet):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int biggest;
  int input;

  std::cout << "First number: ";
  std::cin >> biggest;

  std::cout << "Second number: ";
  std::cin >> input;
  if (input > biggest) biggest = input;

  std::cout << "Third number: ";
  std::cin >> input;
  if (input > biggest) biggest = input;

  std::cout << "Largest number was " << biggest << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
First number: 25
Second number: 64
Third number: 45
Largest number was 64
```

The first number is de-facto the biggest when it's read because it's the only number we know. After that, we read into a different variable, `input` so that we can compare against `biggest`.

There's some repetition though, and this method falls apart pretty quickly as the number of numbers to check grows.

If you know about loops and arrays, your code can be made smaller:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  const std::vector<std::string> ordinals{"First", "Second", "Third"};
  int biggest = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

  for (const auto& i : ordinals) {
    int input;
    std::cout << i << " number: ";
    std::cin >> input;

    if (input > biggest) biggest = input;
  }

  std::cout << "Largest number was " << biggest << '\n';
}
```

We now have to initialize `biggest`, so we give the lowest possible value an `int` can hold. Our loop reads into input and compares against `biggest`. We have the same effect, however, in that `biggest` is always replaced by the first value we enter.

If you are required to actually say "First", etc., it's now trivial to do as well.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  const std::vector<std::string> ordinals{"First", "Second", "Third"};
  std::string ordinalWord;
  int biggest = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

  for (const auto& i : ordinals) {
    int input;
    std::cout << i << " number: ";
    std::cin >> input;

    if (input > biggest) {
      biggest = input;
      ordinalWord = i;
    }
  }

  std::cout << ordinalWord << " number was largest. Value: " << biggest << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
First number: 25
Second number: 64
Third number: 45
Second number was largest. Value: 64
```

Again, this would fall apart if we had much more than three numbers to compare. So instead of words like "First" and so on, we could modify the program to print ordinal numbers.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>  // For simulating larger sets
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string ordinal_suffix(int num) {
  num %= 10;

  if (num == 1) return "st";
  if (num == 2) return "nd";
  if (num == 3) return "rd";

  return "th";
}

int main() {
  // *** Automation setup and execution
  constexpr int setSize = 10'000;

  std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> range(1, 100'000);
  std::vector<int> inputs;

  for (int i = 0; i < setSize; ++i) {
    inputs.push_back(range(prng));
  }
  // *** End of automation setup and execution

  int biggest = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
  int location = -1;

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < inputs.size(); ++i) {
    if (inputs[i] > biggest) {
      biggest = inputs[i];
      location = i;
    }
  }

  std::cout << location + 1 << ordinal_suffix(location + 1)
            << " number was largest. Value: " << biggest << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
8725th number was largest. Value: 99944

~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
433rd number was largest. Value: 100000

~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
7674th number was largest. Value: 99987

~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
891st number was largest. Value: 99995
```